# React, Google map: "Unexpected token <" and "google is not defined" when deployed

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

Estoy recibiendo dos errores, el primero:

```
###Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Y el segundo:

```
###ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

Cuando lo corro en mi computadora todo funciona pero al momento de hacer el deployment en `now.io` los errores aparecen en el navegador (Google Chrome) después de que inicio sesión. Yo supongo que el problema es cuando quiero cargar el mapa pero no estoy muy seguro, el primer codigo es de mi login, y el segundo es el mapa.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import Map from './Map.js';
import { subscribeToTimer } from './api';
import { niPedo } from './api';
import WorkerMainMenu from './Woker_Main_Menu';

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =
        {
            loggedIn: false,
            timestamp: 'no timestamp yet',
            timestamp2: 'no timestamp 2',
            map: true
        }
    this.loggedInMap = this.loggedInMap.bind(this);
    this.loggedInTable = this.loggedInTable.bind(this);
    this.notLoggedIn = this.notLoggedIn.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.openMap = this.openMap.bind(this);
    this.openTable = this.openTable.bind(this);
    subscribeToTimer((err, timestamp) => this.setState({
        timestamp
    }));
    niPedo((err, timestamp2) => this.setState({
        timestamp2
    }));
}
openMap() {
    this.setState({ map: true });
}
openTable() {
    this.setState({ map: false });
}

login() {
    var user = this.refs.inputEmail.value;
    var pwd = this.refs.inputPassword.value;
    var login = {
        user: user,
        pwd: pwd
    }
    axios.post('/api/Login/', { login })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                alert("Intentalo de nuevo");
            }
            else {
                if (res.data.user != null && res.data.user != undefined && res.data.user != "") {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUser', JSON.stringify(res.data.user));
                    var loggedUser = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser');
                    this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
                } else {
                    alert("Intentalo de nuevo");
                }
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
loggedInMap() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">

            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-header">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img className="profile-img-card" src="images/logo.svg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-unstyled components">


                    <li className="success">
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.openMap}  >Home</a>

                    </li>
                    <li className="success">
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.openTable}  >Table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content" style={{ width: "100%" }}>

                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div className="container">
                    <h1>This is the timer value: {this.state.timestamp}</h1>
                    <h1>This is the timer value: {this.state.timestamp2}</h1>
                    <Map />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
loggedInTable() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">

            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-header">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img className="profile-img-card" src="images/logo.svg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-unstyled components">


                    <li className="success">
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.openMap}>Home</a>

                    </li>
                    <li className="success">
                        <a href="#" onClick={this.openTable}>Table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content" style={{ width: "100%" }}>

                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div className="container">
                    <WorkerMainMenu />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
notLoggedIn() {
    return (
        <center>
            <div className="card card-container">
                <img className="profile-img-card" src="images/logo.svg" alt="" />
                <p id="profile-name" className="profile-name-card"></p>
                <form className="form-signin">
                    <span id="reauth-email" className="reauth-email"></span>
                    <input type="email" ref="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required />
                    <input type="password" ref="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="button" onClick={this.login} href="index.html" >Sign in</button>
                </form>
                <a href="#" className="forgot-password">
                    Forgot the password?
            </a>
            </div>
        </center>
    )
}
render() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn && this.state.map) {
        return this.loggedInMap();
    } else if (this.state.loggedIn && !this.state.map) {
        return this.loggedInTable();
    } else {
        return this.notLoggedIn();
    }
}

}
export default MainMenu
```

Y la vista que carga después es la siguiente:

```
import React from "react"
import geolib from "geolib";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker, Polygon } from "react-google-maps"

const defaultOptions = {
  strokeWidth: .5,
  stroke: '#FF5106',
  strokeOpacity: '0.8',
  fill: '#FF4234',
  fillOpacity: '.3',
  onMouseEnter: function (e) {
  },
  onMouseLeave: function (e) {
  }
};

var coordsTemp = { lat: 1, lng: 1 };

const coords = [
  { lat: 21.152895, lng: -101.717851 },
  { lat: 21.152975, lng: -101.717754 },
  { lat: 21.153160, lng: -101.717934 },
  { lat: 21.153106, lng: -101.717998 },
  { lat: 21.153007, lng: -101.717901 },
  { lat: 21.152961, lng: -101.717955 },
  { lat: 21.152908, lng: -101.717902 },
  { lat: 21.152924, lng: -101.717881 }
 ];
const coordsGeolib = [
  { latitude: 21.152895, longitude: -101.717851 },
  { latitude: 21.152975, longitude: -101.717754 },
  { latitude: 21.153160, longitude: -101.717934 },
  { latitude: 21.153106, longitude: -101.717998 },
  { latitude: 21.153007, longitude: -101.717901 },
  { latitude: 21.152961, longitude: -101.717955 },
  { latitude: 21.152908, longitude: -101.717902 },
  { latitude: 21.152924, longitude: -101.717881 }
];

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https:/maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY API KEY]&libraries=places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: '650px' }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
 )((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={17}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 21.152975, lng: -101.717833 }}
  >
    <Polygon paths={coords} options={defaultOptions} />
    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: props.coordsMe.lat, lng: props.coordsMe.lng }} onClick={props.onMarkerClick} label={props.markertext} />}

  </GoogleMap>
)

class Map extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {
    markertext: "Mmmm...",
    isMarkerShown: false,
    coordsMe: { lat: 21.152348, lng: -101.717292 },
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.obtainlocation()
    this.delayedShowMarker()
  }

  obtainlocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      coordsTemp = { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude };
      this.setState({ coordsMe: coordsTemp })
    })
    this.markerInsidePolygon()
  }

  markerInsidePolygon() {
    var isInside = geolib.isPointInside(
      { latitude: this.state.coordsMe.lat, longitude: this.state.coordsMe.lng },
      coordsGeolib
    ) ? 'Sip' : 'Nee'
    this.setState({ markertext: isInside })
  }

  delayedShowMarker = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isMarkerShown: true })
    }, 1000)
  }

  handleMarkerClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isMarkerShown: false })
    this.obtainlocation()
    this.delayedShowMarker()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyMapComponent
        isMarkerShown={this.state.isMarkerShown}
        onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
        coordsMe={this.state.coordsMe}
        markertext={this.state.markertext}
      >
      </MyMapComponent>
    )
  }
}

export default Map;
```

Gracias por adelantado :)

Comment: Hi Kevit, you are in Spanish StackOverflow, if you want help here you need to translate your question to spanish, otherwise you can ask in the English community: stackoverflow.com

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde [so] o accediste directamente a [es.so]? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y nos sería muy útil saber el motivo de la confusión, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara y explicitar que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: @fedorqui pensé que era el único en notar que por algún motivo los usuarios de habla inglesa están siendo dirigidos a este sitio. Lo más probable es que tenga que ver con acceder al sitio desde google

Comment: My bad, I didn´t notice, I will translate:

Estoy recibiendo dos errores, el primero:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Y el segundo:

ReferenceError: google is not defined

Cuando lo corro en mi comoputadora todo funciona pero al momento de hacer el deployment en now.io los errores aparecen en el explorador (Chrome) después de que inicio sesión. Yo supongo que el problema es cuando quiero cargar el mapa pero no estoy muy seguro, el primer codigo es de mi login, y el segundo es el mapa.

I am sorry for my mistake of posting this here on english.

Comment: @Huskie hace tiempo que lo estamos comentando en Meta: [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83)

Comment: no problem Kebit, si es que es raro se está viendo muchos usuarios de habla inglesa que llegan aquí por error @fedorqui Gracias por el enlace, no lo había leído

Comment: @fedorqui ya modifique la pregunta y al igual la respuesta la publique en español, perdón por el inconveniente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la respuesta, lo único que fue necesario es agregar lo siguiente:

```
const google = window.google;
```

Lo encontré en el siguiente link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714895/google-is-not-defined-in-react-app-using-create-react-app

El error Unexpected token < sigue presentándose pero ya corre.